# I am very new to python testing. Help this method with explanation for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

**This function will take input and calls the login function based on input.**

```
def login_features():
print("Choose option to login")
print("1. BDO login")
print("2. GPM login")
print("3. Member login")
login_input = int(input())
switcher = {
    1: bdo_login,
    2: gpm_login, # I am calling the function instance
    3: member_login
}
login = switcher.get(login_input, login_features)
login() # Executing the called function
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to write a test for `login_features()`. Generally, I would refactor the function as such:

```
def execute_login_option(opt_str: str):
    switcher = {...}
    login = switcher.get(login_input, login_features)
    login() # Executing the called function

def login_features():
    print("Choose option to login")
    print("1. BDO login")
    print("2. GPM login")
    print("3. Member login")
    login_input = int(input())
    execute_login_option(login_input)
```

That way you have an easy way to just test `execute_login_option` without having to patch `input()`.

If you need to produce some input, you can use Python's `unittest.mock.patch`:

```
def my_function_with_input():
    test = input("please enter a value")
    return test

with mock.patch('%s.input' % __name__) as patched_input:
    patched_input.return_value = "foo"
    assert my_function_with_input() == "foo"
```

Within the context I redefine the return value of calls to `input()` to be `"foo"`. Similarly, you can set the return value to the desired user input in your testcases for `login_features`.

---

Edit (to answer the question in the comment about how to test functions that do not return values):

If your function does not return a value to assert against, it usually changes the state of the overall system as a *side-effect* (in your example one such a side-effect could be that the user is logged in). See below a minimal example of how to test in such a setting:

```
from unittest import mock

class ClassToTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "A"

    def my_function_with_input(self):
        test = input("please enter a value")
        if test == "foo":
            self.state = "B"
        else:
            self.state = "C"

def my_function_with_input():
    test = input("please enter a value")
    return test

with mock.patch('%s.input' % __name__) as patched_input:
    patched_input.return_value = "foo"

    test_obj = ClassToTest()
    assert test_obj.state == "A"

    test_obj.my_function_with_input()
    assert test_obj.state == "B"  # assert that the state changed to B
```

There are more options and possibilities that can be exploited using the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)-framework.

Comment: I want to know that a method can be tested if and only if that method returns a value.

Comment: The methods which I am calling after login methods, each one of them will be just executed and don't return any value. In that case should I refactor all my methods to return a value.

Comment: @RaghuSreeram: I have added an example testing against a side-effect on the application state.